# Get sigle user ranking position from MySQL 5.7

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get ranking position of single user. I already have the query to get the global ranking but not a single user.

I try:

```
SELECT FIND_IN_SET(`points`, (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`points` ORDER BY `points` DESC) FROM `users`)) AS `rank` FROM `users` WHERE `user` = '1'
```

But this query return repeated rank position if many users have same points.

My global rank query is:

```
SET @rank := 0; SELECT `user`, `points`, @rank := @rank + 1 AS `rank` FROM `users` ORDER BY `points` DESC, `user` ASC
```

But in this case I can't get single user position in rank.
Any idea how I can get single position rank without ranking number repeated?

My MySQL version is 5.7 so can't use funcions like RANK() OVER().
Thanks.

Comment: Eh, you seems better than me in SQL so i am probably saying something wrong but, a single user, use WHERE wouldnt work?

Comment: What result do you want if *many users have same points*? Post sample data and expected results to clarify.

Comment: If I type WHERE it returns @rank variable as 1, and is not the case.

Comment: If for example usar A have 60 points, user B have 40 points and user C have 60 points, it return 1,1,2. and I want 1,2,3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your 1st query, concatenate `user` and `points` and use it in `GROUP_CONCAT()` where you should also extend the `ORDER BY` clause to include `user` as a tie breaker:

```
SELECT FIND_IN_SET(
         CONCAT(`user`, '|', `points`), 
         (
          SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(`user`, '|', `points`) ORDER BY `points` DESC, `user`) 
          FROM `users`
         )
       ) AS `rank` 
FROM `users` 
WHERE `user` = ?
```

Replace `?` with the `user` that you want.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=bfd66cdf684819e2e616ba6c7981b89a).